# Modify wordpress site independently of theme

Tags: wordpress

I am using a WordPress theme in a site. I want to edit the bottom of the page, replacing the WordPress default message and replace it with a custom message. The problem is, the change I want to make should be independent of the theme. I can change that editing footer.php using admin panel. Problem is, I do not want the changes to be reverted as soon as I change the theme. Can anyone suggest how to achieve that? Besides I want to remove the WordPress logo, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the way wordpress works I am afraid.

Anything that is tied to the database (posts, pages etc etc) will remain from theme to theme, but any changes you make to the theme files directly (editing default footer text) are tied to not just that theme, but those specific files. If you change the theme, or update the theme to a new version, your changes will be lost.

You are editing a file, and that file will no longer be in use when you switch theme.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin to create an overlay layer at the bottom of the page but this would be a fairly nasty solution and would be liable to appear differently when you change the theme.

Alternately, a plugin could be used to inject some javascript that modifies the footer but again, would depend on the theme as to what classes/IDs you'd be wanting to modify.

Basically this isn't something that's done!